# nodemailer cannot read req.body

Tags: node.js, axios, nodemailer, body-parser

I have a problem with parse request in node. I can't log `req.body` , because the request is a string. Look at this example:

front.js

```
const data = { name: "John" };
axios.post('http://[address]/sendmail', JSON.stringify(data));
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true,  }));
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("OK")
})

app.post('/sendmail', (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.body) //!!!! here is my problem
   //server shows me: { '{"userName":"Agata"}': '' }
}
```

When I send data by `axios` to my server, he has a problem with parse this data.
I cannot get properties from object because it looks like this:

```
{ '{"userName":"Agata"}': '' }
```

Versions:

- "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
- "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
- "express": "^4.16.4",
- "nodemailer": "^5.1.1",

Help :(

Comment: ok, it works, after few hours I add: app.use(require('body-parser').json()) and now is working, but I changed axios to fetch. Maybe this solution helps someone.

Comment: How is this related to nodemailer?

Comment: @Agata If my answer was useful to you, you can accept it or qualify it so other users with a similar problem can find a solution faster.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript function `JSON.stringify()` convert object into a string, this is the reason why you receive the data in this format `{ '{"userName":"Agata"}': '' }`.

Your `front.js` file should be as follows:

```
const data = { name: "John" };
axios.post('http://[address]/sendmail', data);
```

For `server.js` it is necessary to implement `bodyParser.json([options])` this returns a middleware that only parses json and only looks at requests where the Content-Type header matches the type option. This parser accepts any Unicode encoding of the body and supports automatic inflation of gzip and deflate encodings.

This would be the way to use it with `express.js`

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```